# What happens if you put the BBO before the slits in a delayed choice quantum eraser experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment, quantum-eraser

I've read that you can't detect an interference pattern at D<sub>0</sub> in the image below without correlating with data from D<sub>1</sub>, D<sub>2</sub>, D<sub>3</sub>, and D<sub>4</sub> due to the coherence being broken by the BBO crystal.  Does this coherence-breaking extend to the entanglement of the photons?  What if you were to swap the locations of the BBO crystal and the slits, while leaving the Glan-Thompson prism where it is (after the slits?)  Would the delayed choice aspect of this experiment still come into play while allowing you to see the interference pattern or lack thereof at D<sub>0</sub>?

[image]

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms in title.

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry, BBO = Beta-Barium-Borate, a crystal commonly used for spontaneous parametric down conversion to create entangled photon pairs.